# How can I create a list divider for a collapsible set in jquery mobile

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a collapsible set that looks like this:

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set">
  <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h1>
       <span style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; white-space: pre-wrap;" id="title">This is a really long book title</span><br>
       <span style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal;" id="author">This is the Author of the book</span>
       <span style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; font-style: italic;" id="year">Yr</span>
    </h1>
        <div>Statis</div>        
   </div>
</div>
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to add a list divider to a collapsible set. For example, I used to have a list of items and could add an attribute: data-role="list-divider" which would look like this:

[image]

Is this not possible for collapsible sets?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `list-divider` attribute applies to [listview](http://api.jquerymobile.com/listview/) widgets while the [collapsible-set](http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsibleset/) is a different type of widget.  You can't use the `list-divider` function outside of listview instances.  Of course, you can have a listview contained within a collapsible-set but the list as a whole will either be exposed or hidden.

Comment: I guess that works in a way. What I did was I put my list-divider in a list first, and then below it had my collapsible-set: http://jsfiddle.net/k9ocb8sg/4/